# Should my MX record point to my FQDN?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, fqdn

I finally got postfix up and running for the first time, and want to make sure all things are correct before I 'test' it out, so I can assume unworldly powers stopped it from working and not me.

Assume my FQDN is me.mysite.com, should my MX record point there or to mysite.com?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly - your `MX` record MUST point to hostname that itself points to an `A` and/or `AAAA` record.  An `MX` record cannot directly contain an IP address nor can it point to a `CNAME` record.

Secondly, ideally it should point to whatever your `HELO` name of the server is, but if they're not going to match nomatter what, then it doesn't matter where it points to, just as long as the `A` record resolves to the correct IP address.

You can verify your MX is set up correctly by using nslookup (windows) or dig (linux). On nslookup you would do this:

```
C:\Users\mark.henderson>nslookup
Default Server:  dns.domain.local
Address:  192.168.161.2

> set q=mx
> example.com
Server:  dns.domain.local
Address:  192.168.161.2

Non-authoritative answer:
example.com     MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mail.example.com

mail.example.com       internet address = aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

If you see your correct IP address on that last line, then your MX is working correctly.

Comment: I am a bit confused, my DNS manager can only provide these options for making an MX record.. "Mail Server: mail.mydomain.com, prio: 10, subdomain: (blank)" .. should subdomain be my FQDN? I got an A record from mail.mydomain.com to mydomain.com, but I am not sure what I should set up for MX regarding subdomain if that is needed..

Comment: @John - I don't know what your manager is doing, but if it's got server as `mail.mydomain.com` and you have an `A` record for `mail.mydomian.com` then you should be fine. You can test this by using `nslookup` or `dig`. I'll update my answer with how you can verify this.

Comment: Uh oh.. My site's IP is 74.xxx but it says mail.mysite.com is 174.xxx (which points to my nameservers, ns1.linode.com), do I need to set up the subdomain portion of the MX record to fix this?

Comment: Oh I am an idiot I think.. with my A record I am pointing to DNS not my IP address, I must had copied my DNS and used it in each record forgetting it is not my site's! Let me try that.. Thanks for your help, I understand more about the process :)